# Query lower bound for Majority function using the quantum adversary method

Tags: quantum-algorithms, complexity-theory

Using the quantum adversary lower bound technique, how can one calculate lower bound for Majority function $f:\{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}$ such that $f(x)=0$ if $|x|\leq n/2$ else $f(x)=1$, $|x|$ is the hamming weight of $x$)?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Quantum Computing SE! Please use [MathJax](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49) for properly typesetting mathematical expressions and use the [appropriate tags](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/tags). Go through [How to write a good question?](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/370). I've [edit]ed it on your behalf this time.

Answer (score 2):

First, note that for functions that do not change their value upon permutation of their inputs—or in other words, functions that only depend on the Hamming weight $|x|$ of the input—it is known that the polynomial method tightly characterizes the query complexity, see [Beals et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9802049) In particular, this can be applied to the majority function $MAJ(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ to obtain a tight $\Theta(n)$ bound of the query complexity.

As you asked specifically for a derivation of the $\Omega(n)$ lower bound via the *adversary* method, one can proceed as follows, following [Ambainis’ initial paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0002066) about the adversary method (note that ever since, there were numerous further developments regarding  the adversary method, see for instance [Belov’s thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.3858) and the references cited therein):

Theorem 2 in Ambainis' paper asserts that a lower bound can be shown if one can identify a hard distribution for the function $f$. Technically, this means to find two sets of inputs $X, Y\subseteq \{0,1\}^n$ that lead to different evaluations of the function (i.e., $f(x)\not= f(y)$ for all $x\in X$ and $y \in Y$) and a relation $R \subset X \times Y$ (which makes sure that the two distributions are close in a suitable sense), such that the following hold:

- For every $x\in X$, there are at least $m$ different $y \in Y$ such that $(x,y) \in R$,
- for every $y \in Y$, there are at least $m’$ different $x \in X$ such that $(x,y) \in R$,
- for every $x \in X$ and $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$, there are at most $\ell$ different $y\in Y$ such that $(x,y)\in R$ and $x_i\not= y_i$, and
- for every $y \in Y$ and $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$, there are at most $\ell’$ different $x\in X$ such that $(x,y)\in R$ and $x_i\not= y_i$.

If all this holds, then the query complexity of $f$ can be lower bounded by $\Omega\left(\sqrt{\frac{m m’}{\ell \ell’}}\right)$.

For $MAJ$, one can define an adversary as follows: let $X = \{x : |x|=n/2\}$, $Y = \{y : |y|=n/2+1\}$, and define the relation as $R = \{ (x,y) : |x \oplus y|=1\}$. Then clearly each fixed $x$ can be extended in at least $n/2$ ways to obtain an element in $Y$ that is related to $x$, i.e., $m\geq n/2$. Similarly, $m’ \geq n/2$. For a fixed $x$, and a fixed location $i\in \{1, \ldots, n\}$ there can be at most one bit-vector $y$ that has Hamming distance $1$ from $x$ (namely, this happens precisely when $i$ is not in the support of $x$), so $\ell=1$. By a similar argument, $\ell’=1$. Putting is all together yields the lower bound of $\Omega\left(\sqrt{\frac{n/2 \cdot n/2}{1 \cdot 1}}\right) = \Omega(n)$.